# Play custom formats with C# SoundPlayer class

Tags: c#, asp.net, soundplayer

By default, it can play just .wav. Is there a way to make it play other format?

Answer (score 0):

From the [MS documentation](http://%20%20%20The%20SoundPlayer%20class%20cannot%20play%20other%20file%20types,%20such%20as%20.wma%20or%20.mp3.%20If%20you%20want%20to%20play%20other%20file%20types,%20you%20can%20use%20the%20Windows%20Media%20Player%20control.%20For%20more%20information,%20see%20Using%20the%20Windows%20Media%20Player%20Control%20in%20a%20.NET%20Framework%20Solution%20and%20Windows%20Media%20Player%20Object%20Model%20Reference%20for%20Visual%20Basic%20.NET%20and%20C#%20in%20the%20Windows%20Media%20Player%20SDK.):

"The SoundPlayer class cannot play other file types, such as .wma or .mp3. If you want to play other file types, you can use the Windows Media Player control. For more information, see Using the Windows Media Player Control in a .NET Framework Solution and Windows Media Player Object Model Reference for Visual Basic .NET and C# in the Windows Media Player SDK."

There is a free player for .alaw at: [this site](http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio,articles.aspx). (Not used it myself, so I can't comment on it.)

Comment: My problem is that I need to play headerless 8bit 8KHz .alaw files, that even WMP can't play, so I need something that can use custom drives, or that I can set file properties manualy.

Answer (score 0):

```
Player pl = new Player();
pl.FileName = "123.mp3";
pl.Play();
```

from http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,samples.aspx#sample6